# Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Website\Uploaded-Images\5.jpg' is denied.

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I am trying to upload images in a folder in IIS, but I am getting this error:

> Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Website\Uploaded-Images\5.jpg'
>   is denied.

Answer (score 0):

Either your website's application pool user does not have write permissions to Uploaded-Images or the Uploaded-Images directory may not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your operating systems, You need to grant a minimum of write access to the account IIS_IUSRS on the upload directory.
Hope this helps?